# DMARC report shows DKIM alignment 0%

Tags: gmail, dkim

Our DMARC reports show one of our relays has 0% DKIM alignment:
[image]

The header on a typical email from that address shows it passing SPF and DMARC, and includes Google's DKIM signature, but doesn't include ours. The relay IP is whitelisted in Gmail.

Comment: This may be better suited for [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) since it's specific to G Suite. After a bit of reading, my only guess would be checking if it's using relaxed or strict alignment. I also flagged the question for a mod to potentially migrate it, so just hang tight.

Comment: Our records are set for relaxed, as we've only recently implemented DKIM & DMARC, but we will want to move to strict alignment and rejection of SPF/DKIM failures once we have our bugs worked out.